# Polkadot JS Apps UI - Treasury Proposals - Threshold met but proposals not listed as approved, unable to close

Tags: polkadot-js, pallet-treasury, treasury

We are running a test chain based on the Substrate kitchen-sink node (code here: https://github.com/SparticleConcepts/Geode-Substrate) and using the https://polkadot.js.org/apps/ UI. We can

1. submit a treasury proposal
2. send the proposal to the council for vote
3. vote on the proposal, meeting the threshold for aye votes
4. the proposal will then not allow further voting (assumedly because the threshold has been met)

AT THIS POINT, the proposal will NOT appear as approved, will NOT payout, and CANNOT be closed. It just sits there **well past the spend period waiting period**.

There is plenty of money in the treasury to cover the proposals and each has a unanimous aye vote satisfying the threshold.

Note: Proposals that meet the NAY threshold CAN be closed. But not proposals the meet the AYE threshold.

**Once a proposal meets the threshold for AYE votes, What must be done next to show a treasury proposal as 'approved' and to make it pay out?**

Comment: If you are doing this through polkadot UI, then there is a possibility that it is due to new upgrades to the UI. So just try it with the older version of polkadot js.

Comment: You were spot on! This is definitely a Polkadot-JS problem. For anyone else, older releases are found here... https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found this (https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/7790) suggesting that there are one or more offending props from before the runtime upgrade that cannot be decoded and that, like xmas lights, if there is one bad one, the whole list will act badly. … removed old proposals by disapproving them via extrinsics.

But that did not fix the problem. After much experimentation we have found that **you can approve, disapprove, and close any council motion (or technical committee motion - had the same problem there too) by using extrinsics directly with the chain. The chain code is fine and functioning.** This is a problem with the Polkadot-JS code on the council page and on the technical committee page.